# How to filter SQL query based on multiple values in the same column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to write a query that pulls only employees who are missing their degrees entered into our ERP system. For example, we have a table where their degrees are listed.

```
Employee ID   FName  LName  Degree
100           John   Smith  BA
200           Bill   Jones  BS
300           Alice  Waters BA
300           Alice  Waters MA
400           Joe    Lewis  MA
```

They would like me to pull from this table, only Joe Lewis because he doesn't have a bachelors degree entered in the system, but since he has a master's degree, the assumption is he also has a bachelor's, and someone just missed entering it into the system.

I've tried using EXCEPT filtering on Bachelors degrees, however, that still yields

```
Employee ID   FName  LName  Degree
300           Alice  Waters MA
400           Joe    Lewis  MA
```

And I don't want Alice in the list because she has a bachelors degree coded into the system.

Any thoughts on how I might approach this would be much appreciated.

Comment: hint: find all people with a masters, then subtract off the ones with Bachelors... remaining ones are those of interest.

Comment: You should add code of your attempts to your question.

Comment: Bachelors would be either BS or BA, no? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is just for MA and BA, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select empid, fname, lname
from t
group by empid, fname, lname
having sum(case when degree = 'BA' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when degree = 'MA' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Or, you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where degree = 'MA' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.empid = t.empid and t2.degree = 'BA'
                 );
```

Comment: Exists suggestion worked like a charm! Much thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

You could go with a left join of the Masters subset against the Bachelors subset:

```
select m.EmployeeId, m.FName, m.LName 
from      (select * from Employee where Degree in ('MA')) m
left join (select * from Employee where Degree in ('BA', 'BS')) b
on m.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId
where b.EmployeeId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider to use a query **without** subqueries...

```
SELECT E.EmployeeId, E.FName, E.LName 
FROM Employee AS E
LEFT JOIN Employee AS F ON (E.EmployeeId = F.EmployeeId AND F.Degree = 'BA')
WHERE E.Degree <> 'BA' AND F.EmployeeId IS NULL
```

Or (if BS must be considered as well) :

```
SELECT E.EmployeeId, E.FName, E.LName 
FROM Employee AS E
LEFT JOIN Employee AS F ON (E.EmployeeId = F.EmployeeId AND F.Degree IN('BA','BS'))
WHERE E.Degree <> 'BA' AND E.Degree <> 'BS' AND F.EmployeeId IS NULL
```

keep in mind subqueries are often slow, depending on how many row is concerned...